# Is it possible to make a prepared attack?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

---

I mean, is it possible to spend the character's turn just waiting to something to happen, and then react inmediately out of the assigned slot? For example, aiming at the end of a corridor and then shoot just when an enemy appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are no "prepared attack" rules for the combat system

Assuming you are talking about turns in combat (based on you mentioning assigned slot) there is no prepared or readied action as in other systems in EOTE. If a character is specifically wanting to do something at a later time they should just wait and act in a different PC slot in the initiative order.

Answer (score 1):

For this cases, the FAQ 2.0 (11/20/2017) provided an alternative.

> Q: Can a character hold or delay their action during combat?
>
> A. There is no rule as such for this. A character who wishes to act later
> should simply take a later slot in the initiative order, but there is
> no rule for acting “just before” an enemy does something. The GM
> might call for an opposed roll in such a circumstance if they deem
> it appropriate, perhaps using Cool to resolve a pistol duel for
> example.

You might find the FAQ at the following link:
https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/7d/81/7d8117e8-9360-4118-882d-5476544f5bbc/swrpg_faq_20.pdf